# Address Book Program

Tags: java, addressbook

I'm doing an address book as part of a school assignment and I have it mostly figured out, but I'm stuck on one part. Here's my code first. I have an AddressBook class that contains variables and appropriate getter and setter methods to change/return the information for each person in the book. Then I have a TestAddressBook class with a method main that demonstrates how the address book works. The only thing I'm stuck on is the final requirement, where I'm asked to compare two names and see if they're equal and print the results. I have the program designed the way I want it but for some reason when I do the comparison, it doesn't print the comparison results. It just prints nothing at all. I've got to be missing something obvious. Here's the code for the classes.

AddressBook...

```
public class AddressBook {

private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
private String homeAddress;
private String homePhone;
private String cellPhone;
private String businessPhone;
private String skypeId;
private String facebookId;
private String personalWebSite;

public AddressBook(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName,
                   String homeAddress, String homePhone, String cellPhone,
                   String businessPhone, String skypeID, String facebookID,
                   String personalWebSite) {

                        this.firstName = firstName;
                        this.middleName = middleName;
                        this.lastName  = lastName;
                        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
                        this.homePhone = homePhone;
                        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
                        this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
                        this.skypeId = skypeID;
                        this.facebookId = facebookID;
                        this.personalWebSite = personalWebSite;
                        }

public AddressBook(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public AddressBook(String firstName, String middleName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public AddressBook(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getHomeAddress() {
    return homeAddress;
}

public void setHomeAddress(String homeAddress) {
    this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
}

public String getHomePhone() {
    return homePhone;
}

public void setHomePhone(String homePhone) {
    this.homePhone = homePhone;
}

public String getCellPhone() {
    return cellPhone;
}

public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
    this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
}

public String getBusinessPhone() {
    return businessPhone;
}

public void setBusinessPhone(String businessPhone) {
    this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
}

public String getSkypeId() {
    return skypeId;
}

public void setSkypeId(String skypeId) {
    this.skypeId = skypeId;
}

public String getFacebookId() {
    return facebookId;
}

public void setFacebookId(String facebookId) {
    this.facebookId = facebookId;
}

public String getPersonalWebSite() {
    return personalWebSite;
}

public void setPersonalWebSite(String personalWebSite) {
    this.personalWebSite = personalWebSite;
}

public static String compareNames(String name1, String name2) {
    String nameEquals;
    if ( name1.equals(name2) ) {
        nameEquals = (name1 + " and " + name2 + " are equal names.");
        return nameEquals;
    }
    else {
        nameEquals = (name1 + " and " + name2 + " are not equal names.");
        return nameEquals;
    }
}
```

}

Test Class...

```
public class TestAddressBook {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("ENTRY 1");

    AddressBook entry1 = new AddressBook("Robert", "James", "Smith", "3 Fake St", 
                                         "222-321-8371", "222-423-2382", 
                                         "222-438-2918", "bob483", "bobfb493",
                                         "http://www.freewebhost.com/bob848");

    System.out.println( "First Name:        " + entry1.getFirstName() );
    System.out.println( "Middle Name:       " + entry1.getMiddleName() );
    System.out.println( "Last  Name:        " + entry1.getLastName() );
    System.out.println( "Address:           " + entry1.getHomeAddress() );
    System.out.println( "Home Phone:        " + entry1.getHomePhone() );
    System.out.println( "Cell Phone:        " + entry1.getCellPhone() );
    System.out.println( "Business Phone:    " + entry1.getBusinessPhone() );
    System.out.println( "Skype ID:          " + entry1.getSkypeId() );
    System.out.println( "Facebook ID:       " + entry1.getFacebookId() );
    System.out.println( "Personal Website:  " + entry1.getPersonalWebSite() );

    System.out.println("\nENTRY 2");

    AddressBook entry2 = new AddressBook("Bruce", "Allan", "Carter", "56 Outtamy Way", 
                                         "564-342-8372", "564-283-9832", 
                                         "564-293-3489", "brucie392", "brucieface28",
                                         "http://www.freewebhost.com/carteristheman");

    System.out.println( "First Name:        " + entry2.getFirstName() );
    System.out.println( "Middle Name:       " + entry2.getMiddleName() );
    System.out.println( "Last  Name:        " + entry2.getLastName() );
    System.out.println( "Address:           " + entry2.getHomeAddress() );
    System.out.println( "Home Phone:        " + entry2.getHomePhone() );
    System.out.println( "Cell Phone:        " + entry2.getCellPhone() );
    System.out.println( "Business Phone:    " + entry2.getBusinessPhone() );
    System.out.println( "Skype ID:          " + entry2.getSkypeId() );
    System.out.println( "Facebook ID:       " + entry2.getFacebookId() );
    System.out.println( "Personal Website:  " + entry2.getPersonalWebSite() );

    System.out.println("\nENTRY 3");

    AddressBook entry3 = new AddressBook("Susan", "Anne", "Peters", "6 Madeup Blvd", 
                                         "736-453-1238", "736-392-2385", 
                                         "736-926-2439", "anniep", "susananne",
                                         "http://www.freewebhost.com/Susanspage");

    System.out.println( "First Name:        " + entry3.getFirstName() );
    System.out.println( "Middle Name:       " + entry3.getMiddleName() );
    System.out.println( "Last  Name:        " + entry3.getLastName() );
    System.out.println( "Address:           " + entry3.getHomeAddress() );
    System.out.println( "Home Phone:        " + entry3.getHomePhone() );
    System.out.println( "Cell Phone:        " + entry3.getCellPhone() );
    System.out.println( "Business Phone:    " + entry3.getBusinessPhone() );
    System.out.println( "Skype ID:          " + entry3.getSkypeId() );
    System.out.println( "Facebook ID:       " + entry3.getFacebookId() );
    System.out.println( "Personal Website:  " + entry3.getPersonalWebSite() );



    AddressBook.compareNames(entry1.getFirstName() + " " + 
                             entry1.getMiddleName().charAt(0) + " " + 
                             entry1.getLastName(), 
                             entry2.getFirstName() + " " + 
                             entry2.getMiddleName().charAt(0) + " " + 
                             entry2.getLastName() ); 







}
```

}

Comment: Also, just to be clear, the assignment specifically says that the compareNames method in my AddressBook class is not to print anything, it simply returns the value of the comparison. So i have to print it from the method call in my test class. i.e. something like "name 1 and name 1 are not equal names"

Comment: You do realize that you aren't trying to print the result of `compareNames` in your code?

Comment: So how would I go about printing the results of the name comparison in my test class?

Comment: The same way you print anything else? `System.out.println` - you may want to store the return value of `compareNames` in a `String` variable so the code doesn't become too convoluted.

Comment: *confused* So unless I'm getting something wrong, my test class basically calls the compareNames method from my AddressBook class and gives it the names for entry1 and entry2 as it's paremeters, then the method compares the two names and, depending on the result, stores whether the names are equal or not in the string variable 'nameEquals'. The question is, how do I print that variable in my test class when i run the program. Like where exactly would I put that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you have it good look at this

```
package teteo;

public class TestAddressBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("ENTRY 1");

        AddressBook entry1 = new AddressBook("Robert", "James", "Smith", "3 Fake St", 
                                             "222-321-8371", "222-423-2382", 
                                             "222-438-2918", "bob483", "bobfb493",
                                             "http://www.freewebhost.com/bob848");

        System.out.println( "First Name:        " + entry1.getFirstName() );
        System.out.println( "Middle Name:       " + entry1.getMiddleName() );
        System.out.println( "Last  Name:        " + entry1.getLastName() );
        System.out.println( "Address:           " + entry1.getHomeAddress() );
        System.out.println( "Home Phone:        " + entry1.getHomePhone() );
        System.out.println( "Cell Phone:        " + entry1.getCellPhone() );
        System.out.println( "Business Phone:    " + entry1.getBusinessPhone() );
        System.out.println( "Skype ID:          " + entry1.getSkypeId() );
        System.out.println( "Facebook ID:       " + entry1.getFacebookId() );
        System.out.println( "Personal Website:  " + entry1.getPersonalWebSite() );

        System.out.println("\nENTRY 2");

        AddressBook entry2 = new AddressBook("Robert", "James", "Smith", "56 Outtamy Way", 
                                             "564-342-8372", "564-283-9832", 
                                             "564-293-3489", "brucie392", "brucieface28",
                                             "http://www.freewebhost.com/carteristheman");

        System.out.println( "First Name:        " + entry2.getFirstName() );
        System.out.println( "Middle Name:       " + entry2.getMiddleName() );
        System.out.println( "Last  Name:        " + entry2.getLastName() );
        System.out.println( "Address:           " + entry2.getHomeAddress() );
        System.out.println( "Home Phone:        " + entry2.getHomePhone() );
        System.out.println( "Cell Phone:        " + entry2.getCellPhone() );
        System.out.println( "Business Phone:    " + entry2.getBusinessPhone() );
        System.out.println( "Skype ID:          " + entry2.getSkypeId() );
        System.out.println( "Facebook ID:       " + entry2.getFacebookId() );
        System.out.println( "Personal Website:  " + entry2.getPersonalWebSite() );

        System.out.println("\nENTRY 3");

        AddressBook entry3 = new AddressBook("Susan", "Anne", "Peters", "6 Madeup Blvd", 
                                             "736-453-1238", "736-392-2385", 
                                             "736-926-2439", "anniep", "susananne",
                                             "http://www.freewebhost.com/Susanspage");

        System.out.println( "First Name:        " + entry3.getFirstName() );
        System.out.println( "Middle Name:       " + entry3.getMiddleName() );
        System.out.println( "Last  Name:        " + entry3.getLastName() );
        System.out.println( "Address:           " + entry3.getHomeAddress() );
        System.out.println( "Home Phone:        " + entry3.getHomePhone() );
        System.out.println( "Cell Phone:        " + entry3.getCellPhone() );
        System.out.println( "Business Phone:    " + entry3.getBusinessPhone() );
        System.out.println( "Skype ID:          " + entry3.getSkypeId() );
        System.out.println( "Facebook ID:       " + entry3.getFacebookId() );
        System.out.println( "Personal Website:  " + entry3.getPersonalWebSite() );



      String equal =   AddressBook.compareNames(entry1.getFirstName() + " " + 
                                 entry1.getMiddleName().charAt(0) + " " + 
                                 entry1.getLastName(), 
                                 entry2.getFirstName() + " " + 
                                 entry2.getMiddleName().charAt(0) + " " + 
                                 entry2.getLastName() ); 

System.out.println(equal);


}
}
```

now it is equals, but you must know that in order to do this you should use

compareTo() or comparable look at this

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/difference-between-comparator-and-comparable-in-java.html

What would happen if you use a map? where it depends of a key, you will get duplicate values, i mean if you won't use that it is ok your code, but if you will use it then look an eye in there :)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I knew I was missing something obvious. It all makes sense now. Thank you!